# how to set up a standalone yubikey otp validation server in windows?

Tags: windows, yubico

I want to set up a standalone yubikey otp validation server in windows.Can anyone please help me with the steps I can follow in windows.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have just written a [standalone validation server](https://github.com/bruot/yubival) in Python with Django. I did not test it on Windows, but given the dependencies it requires, there shouldn't be any problem.

Answer (score -1):

The official [YubiKey Validation Server (YK-VAL) installation steps](https://developers.yubico.com/yubikey-val/Installation.html) apply to any GNU/Linux-like system and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is recommended.  A Windows setup guide is not available.

Instead of setting up your own validation server, you could use Yubico's [YubiCloud](https://www.yubico.com/products/services-software/yubicloud) web service for verifying OTPs.

Additionally, if you are looking for an OATH certified TOTP and/or HOTP validation server you can find a list [on the OATH site](https://openauthentication.org/oath-certified-products/).

Edit:

There is a guide for [Self-hosted OTP validation](https://developers.yubico.com/OTP/Guides/Self-hosted_OTP_validation.html) available. But again, the guide uses Ubuntu as a platform, not windows.

Comment: That's not what he is asking for. He is asking for an offline Yubikey validation server, something that can be used in a white lab or a secured facility.